# Uploading .csv to Google Sheets via Gspread

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am using gspread to refresh a worksheet in Google Sheets with data from a .CSV file. As much as I've looked around the web, I'm having a hard time finding what I think should be a clean answer to my question.

I have the .CSV file in my project directory. Here's my code thus far:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import csv

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open_by_key('Spreadsheet Key')
worksheet = sheet.worksheet('Worksheet Name')
worksheet.clear()
```

At this point, I'm not sure what method I should use to mass-upload all the data in the .CSV. I've read that .update_cells() in gspread will only use a single call to the Google Sheets API and is the fastest method, so my question is this:

**Using .update_cells(), how can I iterate through my .CSV to be able to post to Sheets?**

Some info about my .CSV file is that it has 9 columns, but I need the code to handle any changes in the quantity of rows. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, if you are ok with the data going into `A1` on the first spreadsheet, you can use [`gspread.Client.import_csv()`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gspread.Client.import_csv), for a very simple option.

Otherwise, read-on.

To use [`update_cells()`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gspread.models.Worksheet.update_cells), pass it a list of [`Cell()`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gspread.models.Cell) objects.

There are gspread objects that you get from [`worksheet.range()`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gspread.models.Worksheet.range), [`worksheet.cell()`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gspread.models.Worksheet.cell) , [`worksheet.find()`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gspread.models.Worksheet.find), or [`worksheet.findall()`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gspread.models.Worksheet.findall).
(Each of these functions makes a web call when you access them, so try to condense the number of calls.)

Then, for each cell object, change the `cell.value` field, to your csv data.

```
for data,cell in zip(csv_data,worksheet.range()): # Whatever range you need.
    cell.value=data # Sets the cell in *local* sheet to the specified data. (String)
```

So this will change all of the **local** references for that cell to show your csv data. (It is worth pointing out that your data will be converted to a string when it is uploaded.

If you want to read cell data as a number, I remember `cell.numeric_value`, showing up, though I see no reference in the [docs](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#).

Then you would pass all of the now modified Cell items to `update_cells()` and then the google spread sheet would reflect your changes.

You can see other reference material here: https://github.com/burnash/gspread#updating-cells

**Also**, having had to tackle a very similar challenge in the past (json, not csv, but close enough), here is a nice helper function which will take a bunch of columns, and do the busy work of getting the cell object and then sending the `update_cells()` request. 
The code can be found at GitHub.com [here](https://github.com/Team2537/Osborn/blob/ffe3a061ca3198892b78d63ab644a81c744f93f2/spreadsheet_server.py#L506).

```
def update_columns(sheet, row, col, columns, execute = True):
    """Update the specified columns. Row and col are the starting most top left
       cell. Each column should be a list of values. Each list should be the
       same length.
    """
    # Step one, no columns is an error.
    if not columns:
        raise ValueError("Please specify at least one column to update.")

    # Otherwise, get that column length.
    r_len = len(columns[0])
    # First check that all columns are the same length.
    for column in columns[1:]:
        if len(column) != r_len:
            # Variable length.
            raise ValueError("Columns are of varying length.")

    # Start making lists.
    update_cells = []

    # Expand the sheet size if needed.
    if col + len(columns) > sheet.col_count:
        sheet.add_cols(col + len(columns) - sheet.col_count)

    if row + r_len > sheet.row_count:
       sheet.add_rows(row + r_len - sheet.row_count)

    # Get the range of cells to be updated.
    print("Range %s %s %s %s" % (row, col, row + r_len - 1 , col + len(columns) - 1))
    update_range = sheet.range (row, col, row + r_len - 1 , col + len(columns) - 1)

    for c, column in enumerate(columns):

        # Get the range on the sheet for the column.
##        column_range = sheet.range(row, col + c, row + len(column), col + c)
        column_range = (update_range[i] for i in range(c, len(update_range), len(columns)))

        for cell, value in zip(column_range, column):
            # Boolean rational.
            if isinstance(value, bool):
                if str(value).upper() != cell.value:
                    # So its NOT the same.
                    cell.value = value
                    update_cells.append(cell)

            # Use numerical_value for numbers.
            elif isinstance(value, (int, float)):
                # For whatever reason, it looks like gsheets
                # truncates to the 10th place.
                # It seems that 11th & 12th place is almost always correct but
                # can actually differ slightly???
                if cell.numeric_value is None or \
                   truncate(value, 10) != truncate(cell.numeric_value, 10):
                    cell.value = value
                    update_cells.append(cell)

            # And for everything else, string handling.
            elif isinstance(value, basestring):
                if value != cell.value:
                    cell.value = value
                    update_cells.append(cell)

            # Handle None
            elif value is None:
                if '' != cell.value:
                    # Set to ''
                    cell.value = ''
                    update_cells.append(cell)

            else:
                # Other type, error.
                raise ValueError("Cell value %r must be of type string, number, "
                                 "or boolean. Not %s." % (value, type(value)))

    # Now take the list of cells and call an update.
    if execute:
        print("Updating %d cells." % len(update_cells))
        if update_cells:
            sheet.update_cells(update_cells)
        return len(update_cells)
    else:
        return update_cells
```